# Entity Framework returns null with entity set

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to connect the data from one table to the second table its just sucks and I don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

Here's the code:

ContractorData:

```
public class ContractorData
{
    [Key]
    public int ContractorId { get; set; }
    public string ContractorGUID { get; set; }
    public string ContractorName { get; set; }
    public string ContractorSurname { get; set; }
    public string ContractorType { get; set; }
    public string ContractorAddress { get; set; }
    public string ContractorDescription { get; set; }
    public string ContractorIndividualDiscount { get; set; }
    public string ContractorPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContractorEmail { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderData> OrderData { get; set; }
}
```

OrderData:

```
public class OrderData
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; } 
    public string OrderGUID { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public int MagazynItemSKU { get; set; }
    public string ContractorGUID { get; set; }
    public int ContractorId { get; set; }
    public ContractorData ContractorData { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext file:

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options) : base(options) 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Magazyn> Magazyn { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContractorData> ContractorData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payments> Payments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShipmentStatuses> ShipmentStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderData> OrderData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<OrderData>()
            .HasKey(bc => bc.OrderId);
        builder.Entity<OrderData>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.ContractorData)
            .WithMany(bc => bc.OrderData)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.ContractorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

And the repository where I declared what I want to achieve:

```
public async Task<List<ContractorData>> GetContractorOrderAndShipmentsByGUIDAsync(string ContractorGUID)
{
    var record = await _context.ContractorData
            .Where(x => x.ContractorGUID == ContractorGUID)
            .Include(e => e.OrderData)
            .ToListAsync();

    return record;
}
```

In the database it looks like this:

[image: myownpictureofdatabase]

And also the program.cs includes

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ContractorReposiotryInterface, ContractorRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<OrderDataRepositoryInterface, OrderDataRepository>();
```

And this is the output which I'm getting from response body:

```
{
  "contractorId": 0,
  "contractorGUID": "eb397bfe95a74ac09e0e61f3e26fc0df",
  "contractorName": "string",
  "contractorSurname": "string",
  "contractorType": "string",
  "contractorAddress": "string",
  "contractorDescription": "string",
  "contractorIndividualDiscount": "string",
  "contractorPhoneNumber": "string",
  "contractorEmail": "string",
  "orderData": null
}
```

Comment: And what data is in the tables and what did you expect to get?

Comment: You need to add TableAttribute on Entity types.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#use-data-annotations-to-configure-a-model

Comment: @SirRufo i want to get whole order data's for specific user

Comment: "FK_OrderData_ContractorData_**OrderId**" looks suspicious (should be "ContractorId"), are you sure the real fluent configuration of the relationship is what you have shown here?

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok it was my foult, ive drop database and recreate it and now its correct, but the response is still Null.

Comment: This is the allordersget 
``` [
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "orderGUID": "f8f16a4d6b7349d7860652810c04e75b",
    "orderName": "string",
    "orderDate": "2023-01-29T11:15:14.413Z",
    "orderStatus": "string",
    "magazynItemSKU": 0,
    "contractorGUID": "b0513eee9a8b4ccb97183fdce14ca4e3",
    "contractorId": 1,
    "contractorData": null
  }
] ``` so the order have the contractor data, but it's not joining to contractor

Comment: @3milBow The issue is not reproducible. Please add debug lines (or use an actual debugger) inside your `GetContractorOrderAndShipmentsByGUIDAsync()` to verify that the property `record.OrderData` is in fact `NULL` and not an empty collection. Do not check the JSON response, as it might be change the result based on if `record.OrderData` is an empty list. If necessary, provide a full [mcve].